# How does the ESV translate הָעֹבֵר Iin Exodus 30:14?

Tags: exodus, translation-philosophy, moses, kjv, esv

יד  כֹּל, הָעֹבֵר עַל-הַפְּקֻדִים, מִבֶּן עֶשְׂרִים שָׁנָה, וָמָעְלָה--יִתֵּן, תְּרוּמַת יְהוָה

Exodus 30:14 ESV

> Everyone who is ***numbered*** in the census, from twenty years old and upward, shall give the Lord's offering.

Exodus 30:14 ASV

> Every one that ***passeth*** over unto them that are numbered, from twenty years old and upward, shall give the offering of Jehovah.

Exodus 30:14 KJV

> Every one that ***passeth*** among them that are numbered, from twenty years old and above, shall give an offering unto the Lord.

It seems the ESV either translated the verb הָעֹבֵר as numbered or completely ignored it in the above text.

How does the ESV translate this verse?

Answer (score 1):

A very literal translation of Ex 30:14 would be (YLT):

> every one **passing** over unto those numbered, from a son of twenty
> years and upwards, doth give the heave-offering of Jehovah

In the above, the bolded word translates הָעֹבֵר֙ (root form עָבַר) and means to pass over, through or pass on.

The word for "numbered" is הַפְּקֻדִ֔ים (root form פְקַד) and means top attend to, visit or muster, appoint.

Thus, all the OP's versions give the sense reasonably, but all struggle to convey the quintessential Hebrew idiom.  Let me explain further:

- "passing over" means those who would cross into the promised land
- "those numbered, from a son of twenty years and upwards" means those 20 years and older.  In the case of the ESV, "numbered" is unhelpfully translated, "numbered in the census" despite the fact that no census is mentioned.

The NASB renders the sense well:

> Everyone who is counted, from twenty years old and over, shall give
> the contribution to the LORD.